# EF Code First specify how to store a scalar property

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I was wondering if there is a way in EF Code First to specify how to store a scalar property for this exemple:

I have this POCO object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Url> Urls { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to tell EF to store Urls as byte[] using protobuff with maps or any other mechanisms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No unless you create a second `byte[]` property directly in your `MyObject` class. Than you will map a new property and ignore the old property. Once you have this mapping it is up to you if you include the conversion logic directly into the class (to getter and setter of Urls property) or if you use overriden `SaveChanges` and handler for `ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` to do the conversion in scope of data access infrastructure.

You will not be able to query by Urls if you choose that. The only visible property for EF will be the new byte array.

Comment: I was using the trick of two properties, I don't like it very much but for now I will continue with it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it's possible to directly instruct EF to store a collection of items as byte[], but you can use a little workaround.

Add  `NotMapped` attribute to the `Urls` property - it excludes property from EF model, then that add another property `SerializedUrls` that would contain your collection serialized as byte[] and it would be saved to DB. Finally synchronize `Urls` and `SerializedUrls` properies via getter/setter.

```
private byte[] _serializedUrls;
private ICollection<Url> _urls;

public byte[] SerializedUrls { 
  get { return _serializedUrls; }
  set {
    _urls = this.Deserialize(value);
    _serializedUrls = value;
  }
}

[NotMapped]
public ICollection<Url> Urls {
  get { return _urls; }
  set { 
    _urls = value;
    _serializedUrls = this.Serialize(value);        
  }
}

private byte[] Serialize(ICollection<Url> collection) {
  //call protobuf to serialize data
}

private ICollection<Url> Deserialize(byte[] data) {
  //call protobuf to deserialize data
}

public void UpdateSerializedValue() {
  serializedUrls = this.Serialize(_urls);
}
```

Note: since binary representation of the collection changes when you add/remove/change item in the collection, make sure you update `SerializedUrls` if content of the collection changes.